# setup.py isn't including modules

Tags: python, distutils

setup.py includes modules in the same directory it is in but leaves out modules in the site.packages directory and in a lib folder I have added to the pythonpath.

Don't tell me it doesn't just import files like the python interpreter. It should if you name them.

```
programdir-->
programdir-->
datadir
program.py
functions.py
setup.py
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name = "program",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "a program",
    author = "me",
    author_email = "email@email.com",
    url = "http://www.url.com",
    py_modules = ["program", "functions", "tweepy", "anothermod", "webbrowser","" ],
    data_files  = [("data", ["data/intros.txt"])],
    long_description = """
    Descriptttttionnnn
    """
        )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

The setup.py is responsible for bundling and installing YOUR sources, not dependencies. However, you can specify requirements with `install_requires` ([read the manual](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies)). This will be used by pip or setuptools to install the given dependencies, but it will not bundle them either.

Answer (score 0):

Julius is using distutils, not setuptools. This means that `requires` shall be passed to the `setup()` function rather than `install_requires`. See the docs:

[2.4. Relationships between Distributions and Packages](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#relationships-between-distributions-and-packages)